# Why didn't the Catholic Church invent new names for the classical planets?

Tags: catholic-church, names

The Roman Catholic Church had a strong policy of changing or destroying pagan names or other references from several things. Why they didn't rename the classical planets (Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter and Saturn)? They are essentially named after Roman mythological gods (that makes them pagan connotations).

Comment: Probably because it would have confused astronomers, and just wasn't a high priority.  Did the Church ever write any literature discussing the issue?

Comment: Why bother? (a) The names of the planets was specialist knowledge, except for (b) astrology and the Church knew that it couldn't force them to change the planet's names. (c) anyway pagan names were *everywhere* in ancient times and while some Christians changed their pagan names, others didn't and (d) by the time the Church might have been able to effect a change, it didn't matter.   There were always more important things to spend resources on.

Comment: There are also some days of the week and months, other celestial objects. And yeah lots of stuff. 

The inquisition dealt with Galileo if that's any consolation. "And yet it moves"

Comment: Unless we luck out and someone in authority in said organization wrote on this subject contemporaneously (always a possibility!), it can be really tough to objectively answer questions of the form "Why didn't *{historical_entity_x}* do *{this thing I just thought up on my own 2 minutes ago}*?" We're usually on much better ground talking about why active decisions to change things were made.

Comment: `Roman Catholic Church had a strong policy of changing or destroying pagan names or other references`- That is not true. They Christianized pagan temples, rituals and holidays, but didn't "destroy names"! What could that even mean? (They didn't even change the Roman names of the months, unlike the French revolutionaries.) Astrology was taken seriously, astronomy came out of that. The copying and conservation of  Greek and Latin texts (poetry, literature, history, philosophy) took place in Catholic monasteries and was done by church people.

Comment: @cipricus, just to point out, a lot of ancient roman and greek sources were kept with the eastern roman empire, which were not part of the catholic church. Hence the renaissance starting partially due to Constantinople being taken over, with the scholars leaving and taking their books and such. And yes a lot also came from Arabs advancing math and also retaining ancient literature, and trading with Venice and Genoa, who then got better at math.

Comment: I bet the Catholic monks would have copied even atheist philosophers like Democritus and the sophists if they could. It seems Plato an his pupils are to blame for such losses.

Comment: @user14094230 - That is beside the point. Catholics made the translations from Arabic and then from Greek. Lucretius, Virgil and Ovid were copied although they were so pagan and even went clearly against the Christian world-view etc. Even the Renaissance  can be seen (like the Baroque) as Catholic development. I was just trying to disprove the premise of the question. The Church was more of a conservator of ancient culture than even some ancient movements like the Platonist school (who despised poetry).

Comment: @cipricus considering the catholic response to galileo, it's a hard sell to say they have claim over the Renaissance. And that catholics made the translations, because they were Italians, isn't saying much, since, again, the inquisition would've liked to've had a word otherwise.

Comment: @cipricus - Didn't change the Pagan Roman and/or Germanic deity names for the days of the week either.

Comment: You could look on the wikipedia page on the Renaissance, Galileo is mentioned there, as is the fall of Constantinople, and Venice.

Comment: @user14094230  The modernity of Galileo and Copernicus goes beyond the artistic and literary phenomenon of the Renaissance (which anyway was full of "Medieval" beliefs -more so even than the medieval period itself- like astrology, alchemy and magic). Like G. Bruno, they read and thought in a world of ideas and values that cannot be defined outside the Catholic culture. And when they revived pagan ideas was because the ancient text were still there.

Comment: @user14094230 - What Galileo has to do with the pagan names of the planets? Copernicus and Galileo faced resistance and persecution because the church was following the ancient theories of Aristotle: a proof that Catholic attachment to antiquity was real! The OP has the impression that the opposite was true. -- You sending me to study Wikipedia (have you read Burkhardt?) will not help change my impression that I'm scolded by a teenager.

Comment: @user14094230 - Can you indicate the wikipedia article were you read that `catholics made ... translations, because they were Italians`? And what does that mean? Many translations from Arabic happened in Spain (Toledo).

Comment: Question appears to be based on unsupported assumptions.  Recommend either support or remove those assumptions. [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Isidore of Seville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isidore_of_Seville) is a well-known writer of the 7th century, whose encyclopedical works were widely read in the early middle ages.

His main work, the [Etymologiae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymologiae) tries to collect the essence of knowledge of Antiquity. It also contains a chapter about astronomy. Concerning the names of the planets, he condems their naming after false gods:

(English [translation](https://books.google.de/books?id=3ep502syZv8C&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA105#v=onepage&q&f=false) Stephen A. Barney et al., Cambridge University Press 2006)

> Planets are stars that are not fixed in the sky as the rest are...Their Greek names are Phaeton, Phaenon, Pyrion, Hesperus, and Stilbon. The Romans have consecrated them with the names of their gods, that is, Jupiter, Saturn, Mars, Venus, and Mercury. Themselves deceived, and wishing to deceive others into the worship of those who had granted them something in accordance with their desires, they would point out stars in the sky, and say that this on was Jupiter's and that one was Mercury's, and this vain belief was born. The devil strengthened this errroneous belief, and Christ overturned it.

But no "Christian" names are then given.

Another work, [De natura rerum](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VyxbAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false), On the nature of things, is a complilation of christian thoughts about natural history, giving a lot of weight to the scriptures and the writings of the Church Fathers.

Chapter 26: De nominibus atstrorum, *The names of the stars* has some general thoughts about the naming of stars (Chapter 13 handles the planets, but just uses their names as a given):

> Legitur in Iob dicente domino: 'Numquid coniungere vales micantes stellas Pliades et gyrum arcturi poteris dissipare? Numquid producis Luciferum in tempore suo et vesperum super filios terrae consurgere facis?' Et iterum alibi: 'Qui facit arcturum et Orionem et Hyadas.' Haec nomina stellarum dum in scripturis sacris legimus vanis deliramentis poetarum adsensum non praebeamus, qui falsis opinionibus ista in astris ex hominum nominibus vel aliarum creaturam vocabulis inposerunt. Ita enim stellarum quarundam gentilium sapientes nomina sicut et dierum indiderunt.
>
> Quod vero isdem nominibus sacra utitur scriptura, non eorum idcirco vanas adprobat fabulas, sed faciens ex rebus visibilibus invisibilium rerum figuras ea nomina pro cognitione hominum ponit, quae late sunt cognita, ut quidquid incocgnitum significat, facilus per id quod est cognitum humanis sensibus innotescat.

(Translation by [Google translator](https://translate.google.com).)

> It is read in Job saying to the Lord: 'Are you able to unite the twinkling stars of the Pleiades and to dispel the whirlwind of Arcturus? Dost thou bring forth Lucifer¹ in its season, and make the evening rise upon the children of the earth?' [Job 38:31-32] And again in another place: 'Who makes Arcturus and Orion and the Hyades.' [Job 9:9] While we read these names of the stars in the sacred writings, let us not give assent to the vain delirium of the poets, who, by false beliefs, have imposed these names on the stars from the names of men or the terms of other creatures. For thus the wise men of certain Gentiles gave names to the stars, just as they did to the days.
>
> But the fact that the sacred scriptures use the same names does not therefore approve of their vain fables, but, making figures of invisible things out of visible things, sets forth those names for the knowledge of men, which are widely known, so that whatever signifies the unknown, may easily be known to the human senses by that which is known.

In short: the names of the stars are made-up by men anyway, let's leave them alone so that everyone knows what we are talking about.

¹ *Lucifer* here refers to the name of the Morning Star. Venus in Antiquity was considered to be two different stars, the Evening Star Hesperos/Venus, and the Morning Star Phosphoros/Lucifer.